# Time Series Oriented IoT Platform

Tags: database, rest, time-series, publish-subscribe, iot

I have an embedded "thing" which generates data samples from several sensors at 1kHz. It has a fairly bandwidth constrained 3G connection to the outside world.

Does anyone know of a platform which can provide the following (or at least a subset of the following):

1. A Publish/Subscribe interface to send/receive real time data streams
2. A (very) compact/compressed time series oriented transmission protocol for bandwidth-constrained devices
3. A database to store the data samples in a compact format
4. A REST-ful query-based API to retrieve historic data samples
5. A GUI javascript? dashboard capable of real time and historic graphing capabilities

The majority of platforms I have found are designed to work in the domain of  seconds rather than milliseconds and/or use string-heavy data formats such as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single solution, try [ATSD](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/), it does all of the above.

For example you can connect your device to an MQTT server (publish/subscribe interface) that talks to ATSD, allowing you to send/receive real time data streams. Open source sketches for this are available [here](https://github.com/axibase/arduino/tree/master/dataTransmission).